# node cannot find express module?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am unaware what is causing this problem, because I thought it should be working. I do have expressed installed, at least according to npm:

```
C:\Users\phucker\Desktop>node init.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\phucker\Desktop\init.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

C:\Users\phucker\Desktop>npm express -v
1.3.2

C:\Users\phucker\Desktop>
```

the code contained in init.js is

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have `express` installed locally in your `node_modules` folder. Check your `node_modules` and install it again if it is not there

Comment: Why? What is the point of being able to install something globally if it can't be used "globally"?

Comment: @Sosukodo a very good explanation for this is on the [npm blog](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation) global installations are good if you want to use the executable from your shell. For using them as a library in your program it is preferable to install them locally. Though you can create symbolic links from global installations as well.

Answer (score 5):

`npm express -v` doesn't show the version of Express that you have installed, it shows the version of `npm`.

To show which version of Express you have installed, try this:

```
npm ls express
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not your problem, but it is often confusing distinction between global and local installations for beginners. If you use `require('module_name')` in your code, each module must be installed locally using `npm install module_name` or using dependencies in `package.json`.

Global installation is only for running commands like `express my_new_project`.

You can list all installed local modules for actual directory using `npm list` and all global ones running`npm list -g`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following if you have installed express globally

i.e using  the command `npm install -g express`

1. Check if express module is imported in your code using

   var express = require('express')
2. On windows check if the path `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm` is on the PATH environment variable

For installations that do not have express installed globally

1. Navigate to you folder C:\node project
2. Do a local installation of Express using `npm install express`
3. Import express module in your code using `var express = require('express')`